# Instant Run fails with "Android Plugin for Gradle version 1.5.0 does not support Instant Run. Please update to version 1.5.0"

Tags: android, android-studio

When running my Android App with Android Studio 2.0, Instant Run fails with this message, even though I have configured my app module to use v2.0.0 of the Gradle plugin:

> Android Plugin for Gradle version 1.5.0 does not support Instant Run. Please update to version 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio does not detect the correct plugin version when it is configured in the app-module `build.gradle` (e.g. `MyProject/app/build.gradle`). Add the plugin to your buildscript classpath in the **root** `build.gradle` (e.g. `MyProject/build.gradle`).

Answer (score 2):

Instant run requires Gradle version 2.0.0. Update your `build.gradle` to include the following instead.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
}
```